# c# multi-threaded queue items are null

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

My application is a multi-threaded application. I use threads and Tasks to enqueue  and dequeue items from ~4 queues using locks.
Sometimes, when i dequeue, the item is null and when i look inside the queue i can see some other items are null too (e.g the 5th item is null).
whenever i enqueue i always create a new item, so it being null is impossible. at first i thought that another thread is messing with my items. but when i saw that the 5th item was null too,while the 3rd, 4th and 2nd wasn't i realized that its impossible because you cant touch the 5th item before dequeueing  the previous items.
i cannot share my code.
is someone familiar with that kind of situation?
what could be the cause?

----------------------------------**EDIT**-----------------------------
the class that enqueues the queue inherits from serial port and enqueues like this:

```
if(BytesToRead>0)
{
byte[] data=new byte[BytesToRead];
Read(data,0,data.length)
MyClass c=new MyClass(){m_data=data, m_tod=DateTime.Now};
_dataQueue.Enqueue(c);
}
```

and the classes that dequeues vary but the idea is similar:

```
lock(_sync)
{
var item=_dataQueue.dequeue();
}
```

when i dequeue i get null. as you can see i use `DateTime.Now` so its really wierd that it goes null. I mean if a thread uses this so the item shouldnt be there right?
each class that uses the queue has a copy of it. and inside every class there are about 3 threads that uses the queue

Comment: make sure the items aren't null... i mean, when you create them check they weren't created as null, check if the GC goes through them: implement iDisposeable and set a breakpoint in Dispose

Comment: Does sound like a race condition. Gonna be hard to fix without at least knowing what the thing is supposed to do, even if we can't see actual code. Maybe mock it up for us?

Comment: What queue class?  C# has concurrent/blocking collections - are you not using them?

Comment: Post your code so that we can help you

Comment: @LiranElisha I disagree with GC concept of you, how can GC collect an object when it have managed references?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel this is nice in theory but i have seen the GC doing some carzy unexplained things in my life...

Comment: @LiranElisha I've also seen that but only when object is not being used in further code to execute from the current execution point!

Comment: @MartinJames i tried to use ConcurrentQueue just now and i'm still checking it.

Comment: Your call to `Enqueue` isn't protected by a lock. You need to lock the queue when adding items. Also: you probably don't want to use `ConcurrentQueue` directly. Use `BlockingCollection`, which presents a much nicer API. (`BlockingCollection` is a wrapper around `ConcurrentQueue`)

Comment: @JimMischel care to go go into details?
why shouldt i use concurrentQueue ?

Comment: @user2603659: As I said, `BlockingCollection` is easier to use. It is a much nicer API wrapper around `ConcurrentQueue`. But use whichever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that its impossible because you cant touch the 5th item before dequeueing the previous items.

That reasoning does not hold when a collection that is not thread-safe is used from multiple threads. A race-condition can lead to all sorts of symptoms.

So best thing is to check your locking. If possible, post a mock-up of the code.

After the ----Edit---- :

Your are not locking around the Enqueue. The basic fix:

```
//_dataQueue.Enqueue(c);
lock(_sync)
{
   _dataQueue.Enqueue(c);
}
```

Comment: inserting an item while dequeueing an item should result in a null item inserted to the queue? how's that?

Comment: Inserting and/or Dequeueing without thread-safety can result in _anything_. When you handle the `null`s and keep running you're likely to see other problems.